# Responsive text wrap around an image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

I need text to wrap around an image (200px by 200px) until a portion of the wrapped text on the side gets too narrow, at which point i want the text box to go under the image.

This is what i mean:

[when the screen is wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0REJ.jpg)

[when the screen is more narrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfOop.jpg) 
This is where i want the wrapping to stop. I dont want the text to wrap in a way that it displays skinny stacks of text like this:

Lorem 
Ipsum 
is  
simply 
dummy
text
of the
printing 
and blah blah Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

```css
article { 
  margin: 20px; 
  font-family: verdana, sans serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
p { 
  margin-top: 20px; 
}
.example-container {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.caption {
  font-style: italic;
  color: BlueViolet;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.caption-subhead {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.image-example {
  float: left;
  background-color: #555555;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align:center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin: 5px 20px 10px 0;
}
.hyphenate {
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<article lang="en">
  

<div class="example-container">
  
    <div class="image-example">Image Example</div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
</div>

   
</article>
```

Comment: This is the behaviour i currently have. I edited my post to better explain what the problem is. Thanks anyways!